# Use a different `google-services.json` when testing in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, testing

I am working on an Android application that uses Firebase for data storage. I'd like to run JVM unit and instrumentation tests that will be in the app/src/tests and app/src/androidTest directories, but I don't want to use the production database `google-services.json` that is currently in the root `/app` folder. I have created a testing database in Firebase console with its own `google-services.json` file. How do I tell Android to use that `google-services.json` when running unit or instrumentation tests?

Answer (score -1):

You can find a tutorial on this in the Android developer documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors).

You can set up multiple product flavors in your build script and then you can put your specific files according to the package structure.